# How does the HTML5 outlining structure called

Tags: html

I've read somewhere couple of days ago an article about using multiple `h1` tags in the same page and the **name** of the structure where you can use multiple `article`/`header`/`footer` tags and so on... And today my OCD kicked me on the back and I can't remember the name of this outlining structure and can't find that particular article.

Sorry for broad/stupidly unclear question, but perhaps someone will actually know what am I talking about and can help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `<article>`, `<header>`, `<footer>` etc is called semantic HTML.